# Modular progress bar

Tags: css, angular, typescript, animation

I am trying to make a modular animated progress bar that I can use like so:

```
<bar [type]="'health'" [percentage]="'80'"></bar>
```

It is working to the point I need to set different percentages. It does not need to be completely dynamic, just once the page loads it fill up the bar to X percentage I specify above.

```
*bar.component.html*
<div class="bar-wrapper">
  <div class="bar-label">CSS</div>
  <div class="bar-container">
    <div class="bar-fill" [style.width.%]="percentage" [@barAnimation]="state"></div> <!-- Tried several ways to set the CSS but it remains how I define it in the SCSS file. -->
    <div class="bar-percentage">{{percentage}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*bar.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bar',
  templateUrl: './bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('barAnimation', [
      state('collapsed, void', style({ width: '0%'})),
      state('expanded', style({ width: '*'})), // <--- the width needs to be altered for each component.
      transition('* => expanded', [animate("4s cubic-bezier(0, -0.75, 0.25, 1)")])
  ])]
})
export class BarComponent implements OnInit {

  public state = "expanded";

  @Input() public type: String;
  @Input() public percentage: String;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.type + ", " + this.percentage);
  }

  public startAnimation() {
    this.state = "expanded";
  }
}
```

After fiddling around with this for way too long I figured `*` should do the trick on the width property. I can change my `scss` file manually and the bar works properly. So I guess I just need to set the CSS width property somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `barAnimation`. You are making this more complicated than it needs to be. :)

Just use a simple CSS transition on width. Here is some pseudo code that should set you in the right direction:

CSS:

```
.bar {
    transition: width .5s ease;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="bar" [style.width.px]="width"></div>
```

Component:

```
@Component({...})
export class BarComponent {
    @Input() width: number = 0;
}
```

Any time the `width` property gets modified, the bar width will grow and it will grow in an animated style based on that transition in the CSS.

---

To test it out, just set a timer and increase the width to 50:

```
@Component({...})
export class BarComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() width: number = 0;

    ngOnInit() {
        setTimeout(() => this.width = 100, 1000);
    }
}
```

After one second, the width will grow to 100 pixels.

If you want to swap out pixels for percentage, go right ahead -- it shouldn't have any effect on the animation itself.

Comment: Now it just gets set to the width I specify in the first place. No transition is taking place. What I eventually want is to trigger a couple dozen of these bars when they are within the clients viewport.

Comment: Sorry, this is untested. Try changing the CSS transition to `all` instead of `width`, add a `display: block`, etc. But this is the general simple idea. Also, you can wrap this any way you'd like and pass in much more `@Input()`'s. Let me know if it still doesn't work and I'll actually give you a tested solution; just wrote this on the fly.

Comment: Yeah thanks. Got it, I just start at `0` and alter that width whenever I want.

Comment: Nice! Glad it works. I, too, sometimes get lost in the maze of trying to build complex Angular animations lol. CSS is usually a good start for the simple stuff.